# How to render info window content dynamically

Tags: angular, google-maps, agm-direction, agm-map, agm-core

I'm using the agm-direction package to display route information on the agm-map (https://www.npmjs.com/package/agm-direction).

I would like to know how I can render the content of the infowindow for especially the origin marker:

[image: marker options]

the output looks like this:

[image: info window output]

I would like to do something like this, so I can build a more complex infowindow:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using agm-info-window you can put your dynamic text into agm-info-window

```
 <agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">

      <agm-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">

        <agm-info-window>
          <h3><strong>Howdy!</strong></h3>
          <p>You are here!</p>
        </agm-info-window>

      </agm-marker>

    </agm-map>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Infowindow** is string, so if you want to process your variables than write it within **``** See Below example

```
`<h1>${vehicles[0].name}</h1>`
```

Comment: Ok thanks, but is there a way to compile a component to a string, like it was possible with $compile in v1?

Comment: Sorry, but i do not have idea about it.